# how to present a documentation from user point of view?

Tags: documentation

I am preparing documentation on a software product for my company. 
Can anyone provide me suggestions for preparing a better document will help me a lot.
Are screenshots necessary while preparing the documentation ?

Comment: This needs a great deal more information before it can be answered in a stellar manner. This isn't to take away from Sayusi's or Anna's answers, but because you don't talk about what your problem is, we have no way of knowing how to actually solve it. Further, I'm not sure if software documentation is considered on topic by the community here, but I will bring it up on meta to open a discussion around it.

Comment: I mean that how to present a documentation from user point of view? @corsiKa

Comment: @kevalkumar you still need to provide more information to allow us to provide you with an excellent answer. Are you dealing with trained users or the general public? Do you need to document a single function or everything from install on? Software documentation is its own discipline and many testers don't have much experience with it.

Comment: @KatePaulk i am dealing with trained users and the software application is based on construction domain .I need to document everything from install on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing documentation for a software product is not easy. When I did it I had to keep in my mind that how the users use the software and I built up the main line of the document. Basically, the documentation followed the user journeys.

But, later we were able to define the different roles who use the software. So to have higher satisfaction I upgraded the documentation which followed the user journeys of the different roles who use the software.

After that I had to learn their language (they were accountant and finance experts) and I used their language in the documentation. Later I asked a few of them to review it before it will be published for all.

Based on this little experience whenever I have to write something I ask the next questions to identify the goals of the documentation:
- who will use the software?
- how they will use it?
- what the main user journeys are?
- what the main roles are?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my answer is trite.

When you prepare the documentation, try to be as specific as possible when describing it. Imagine that you are a potential user that know nothing about the product.

Comment: yes anna you may be right ... thnxx :)